# Javascript: Global variable within function

Tags: javascript, variables

Is there a way to set a global Javascript function within HTML.

I can only pass it as a function like

```
  PostComment(this.content)
```

So i can only access it inside the PostComment function. Is there a way to access it in another function?

Answer (score 1):

Just create the function as normal in your `<script>` tags like this

```
function postComment(content){
      //process content
}
```

it will be placed in the global namespace. Such practice is actually frowned against as it pollutes the global namespace. It is best practice to namespace your functions like

`myNamesSpace.postComments(this.content)` I assume the `this` here refers to an enclosing object, `myNamespace` in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can always attach stuff to the global object, which is usually `window` in a browser.

```
window.myGlobalVar = ...;
```